# Restrict website to access specific country

Tags: php, geolocation, ip

I am wondering if it's possible to make my website only available to a specific country.
So anyone who tries to visit the website outside the specific country, will not have access.

I was thinking of getting a php IP Geo Locator script and do a redirect if they IP address is from the country I decide.

How would you guys recommend it?

Thank you.

***EDIT***

This doesn't have to be 100% accurate. Just need the php code that will do what I need.
The country is Romania by the way. Thanks! :)

Comment: First, there's no **absolute**  list of IP addresses and countries.  Second, it's easy to have a proxy server in-country that forwards requests from out-of-country.  Third, I could be a citizen who's travelling.  My local ISP has an IP address that indicates I'm not in that country.  But I'm a citizen and want to see the in-country content.  So, it probably won't work very well at all.

Comment: @S.Lott Thanks dude. Appreciate it. I found this website with IP Addresses for Different countries though [http://www.nirsoft.net/countryip/](http://www.nirsoft.net/countryip/) Would this help me?

Comment: If you think it will help, enjoy.  Routers can defeat this.  Citizens who are accessing your site from outside the country won't be served properly.  But for that exact list of IP addresses -- and no others -- your scheme will obviously work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer depends on what you mean by "available to a specific country".

1. What if an in-country computer has an IP address not on your list?  That computer won't have access, but it's located in country.
2. What if an out-of-country computer has an IP address on your list?   That computer will have address, but it's not located in country.
3. What if a router with an in-country IP address forwards requests from out-of-country?  What if an in-country router is part of the [TOR network](https://www.torproject.org/)?
4. What if a citizen leaves the country and wants to get access to your in-country web site from another country?  The citizen will have an IP address not your list and will be denied access.

Until you define "available to a specific country" your question cannot be answered.

Comment: Ok man, it doesn't have to be THAT precise. If they are from the country, but are living somewhere, it's fine. If they are from somewhere else, but are in the country, it's fine. Everything else is fine too. I just need to know how to do it... :)

Comment: "it's fine"?  It's fine that they can't get in because their IP address is from the wrong country?  Here's the point.  You need to **update** the question to precisely specify what you actually mean by "available to a specific country".  After you **update** the question with a precise specification of what you need to know, we might be able to answer your question.  "I just need to know how to do it." is pretty vague.  Do you not know PHP?  Do you not know how to check headers?  What is stopping you?