# Block IP address out side india

Tags: c#, .net, iis-7.5

I deployed the .net application in IIS. It should be accessible within India only. If the request comes from outside of India, we have to prohibit it.

IIS has an option to allow or deny based on IP address range. But, I need to know the IP address range in India

Please suggest...

Comment: Have a look here. [Restrict website to access specific country](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8384421/restrict-website-to-access-specific-country)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use some third party API like [IP Address Geolocation XML API](http://ipinfodb.com/ip_location_api.php) as you cannnot identify the country from the IP Addresss directly. Here is an [example](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/118711-class-countryip-vbc%23/) as to how you can find the country using the IP Address.

The code from the source to find the country is this:

```
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Collections.Specialized;

public class CountryIP {
    public string GetCountryByIP(string ipAddress) {
      string ipResponse = IPRequestHelper("http://ipinfodb.com/ip_query_country.php?ip=", ipAddress);

      XmlDocument ipInfoXML = new XmlDocument();
      ipInfoXML.LoadXml(ipResponse);
      XmlNodeList responseXML = ipInfoXML.GetElementsByTagName("Response");

      NameValueCollection dataXML = new NameValueCollection();

      dataXML.Add(responseXML.Item(0).ChildNodes(2).InnerText, responseXML.Item(0).ChildNodes(2).Value);

      string xmlValue = dataXML.Keys(0);

      return xmlValue;
    }

    public string IPRequestHelper(string url, string ipAddress) {
      string checkURL = url + ipAddress;

      HttpWebRequest objRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
      HttpWebResponse objResponse = (HttpWebResponse)objRequest.GetResponse();

      StreamReader responseStream = new StreamReader(objResponse.GetResponseStream());
      string responseRead = responseStream.ReadToEnd();

      responseStream.Close();
      responseStream.Dispose();

      return responseRead;
    }
}
```

Some other API like **[HostIp.Info](http://www.hostip.info/use.html)**

Comment: Thanks. actually our project is banking sector. so they won't allow us to call third party api for security reason.

Comment: @sankarapandian:- I am afraid that without using any external API you will not be able to achieve that as by just using the IP Address without using any API you cannot identify the country.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to do this within your application, though it's simple enough.

1. Get a Geo-IP database or access to a Geo-IP webservice (if using a webservice it would be a very good idea to cache IPs you've seen in the past e.g. month rather than hit it over and over).
2. Have a module bound to the `BeginRequest` event.
3. In the module, check the IP against the service. It will either be believed to be in India (pass), believed to be local (pass), believed to be in another country (fail) or of an unknown location (pass or fail depending on whether you want to err on the side of blocking some Indian users or allowing some non-Indian users).
4. For a fail, respond with the error message and stop all further processing.

Then use a proxy service like Hola ([this is a referral-link for a free trial on their premium service](http://hola.org/referral_signup?referrer_uid=basic%2Fjon%40hackcraft.net&ref=footer&medium=manual), but really their free service will probably be more than adequate for what you need) to test it from different countries.

(Of course, likewise people you block can use exactly the same approach to get around your restriction).

There will be some false-positive and false-negatives because geo-ip databases tend not to be perfect. E.g. there's a company I know of in Dublin, Ireland whose office seems to be just outside Paris, France because they use a subset of a range of their French parent office, and so on.

Comment: Thanks. actually our project is banking sector. so they won't allow us to call third party api for security reason.

Comment: Then "Get a Geo-IP database or access to a Geo-IP webservice" becomes "Get a Geo-IP database". There are companies like MaxMind that will license databases you can host yourself, along with providing updates to keep your info current.

Comment: @sankarapandian:- Jon is talking about this: http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/geolite/

Comment: @sankarapandian:- Likewise there is http://www.ip2nation.com/ as well which provide Mysql database

Comment: @RahulTripathi actually I was talking about one of their commercial services, but the free one you like to may or may not be of use to Sankara, and will certainly be of use to me, so thanks for that!

Comment: @JonHanna:- You are welcome. I got that, I just wanted to show the path to OP:)

Comment: @RahulTripathi I'd been thinking of the 12 USD per month one at https://www.maxmind.com/en/geoip2-databases not knowing about the free one at all.

Comment: @JonHanna:- Looks like I saved few dollars for you ;)